# Can't find out why my program won't read analog values (Using MCP3004)

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, spi, c, wiringpi

I am using wiringPi and C. I have a flame sensor and a MCP3004 ADC. Here is the program that I wrote, but I can't figure out why it won't read the analog values from the flame sensor.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <mcp3004.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BASE 200
#define SPI_CHAN 0

int main(void) {

int channel;
int x;

if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
    exit(1);

mcp3004Setup(BASE, SPI_CHAN);
for (channel = 0; channel<8; ++channel) {
    x=analogRead(BASE+channel);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    delay(1000);
}
return 0;
}
```

My program runs but it just outputs 0s. The wiring is correct and the sensors and MCP3004 work fine, I tested it with a python program and it gets the job done.

So the only problem is in my C code.

Comment: Well an MCP3004 only has 4 channels (0-3).  I'd expect erroneous results for non-existent channels 4-7.  As a general principle have you checked the status returned by those functions you call which return a status?  Perhaps one is returning you a status indicating an error which you are ignoring.

Comment: To further the above comment, looking at the source, `mcp3004Setup()` will return false on error and true on success, so perform a check there... for example: `if ! mcp3004Setup(...){exit(1);}`

Comment: thanks for replying guys.. So basically what happened now is that for some reason my c program works and the python program that I used to check if I connected the mcp and fire sensors correctly, doesn't. I swear to god i didn't touch anything no idea what happened. Fortunately this program works fine. Thanks so much for fast replying and interest though guys.  I will also post here another code that works for mcp3008 (a little bit more advanced) for future coders/developers :)
http://shaunsbennett.com/piblog/?p=266

Answer (score 0):

The [link here](https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/lesson-21-flame-sensor-sensor-kit-v2-0-for-b-plus.html) may help. They have the wiring shown pretty clearly and example programs for Python and C users.